# validation of checkout fields in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce, checkout

how to validate first_name and last_name in checkout fields in woocommerce that only takes alphabetic letters?
e.g {a-z}

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add code to show what you have attempted

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` WordPress action hook and `if( preg_match( '/\d/', $fields[ 'billing_first_name' ] ) )`  conditional statement to check whether it contains numbers or not.

Example: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/custom-checkout-validation.html#validate_name